# I need help adding a chain with physics to an animated/rigged model

Tags: animation, physics, rigidbody

I had a 3d model that is animated, however, I now want to add some hanging chains with physics to the animation. I had the chain with rigid body, however, I cannot seem to attach it to the belt and have it move with the rig. I will essentially be making a chain "skirt". Thanks for your help[image]

Comment: Is your chain with rigid body working okay?  It's possible, now, to make a rigid body chain, but it's very finicky and requires a lot of work.  If you've already done that work and just need to know how to attach a set of rigid bodies to a deforming mesh, then it's just a matter of making an animated-type rigid body "anchor" that is vertex-triangle-parented and then using a point constraint to join it to the topmost link's rigid body.

Comment: I have been able to link the top most chain to the animation by parenting it with the rig, then using the data transfer modifier to link it to the body. However, I cannot figure out how to apply this to the rest of the chain, while keeping the chains' rigid body as separate.

Comment: You don't do it to the rest of the chain.  The rest of the chain moves because of its connnection to the anchor.  However you have that set up (collision or constraints.)

Comment: I have been able to anchor the top chain, but then the rest of it just falls down, it will not stay looped with the top anchor

Comment: Okay, then you need to get the chain set up with physics; I must have misunderstood what you were saying.  Is your intention to render in Blender?  That affects the answer.

Comment: No worries. Yes I will eventually render it in blender. The chain already has physics and is moving on its own, but when I attach the anchor to the rig, the rest of the chain and its physics do not apply

Comment: Maybe you should link a file so I can see myself how you have the physics set up on the chain.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.